# tensorflow new op that uses external libraries

Tags: build, tensorflow

I wrote an op that reads data from EXR files.

The code is able to compile, but when I call `tf.load_op_library('custom_ops.so')` i have an `NotFoundError: libcustom_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK3Imf9InputFile6headerEv` error.

I suspect this is because my cc file requires `libopenexr` library. My question is how to tell tensorflow to load the additional libraries as well?

An alternative may be, to include the additional library in my `custom_ops.so`.

For this, I tried calling in CMake

```
add_library(custom_ops SHARED ${SOURCES} back_warp.cu.o ${OpenEXR_LIBS})
```

but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm very sorry. The problem seems to be solved by adding the following to the CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(custom_ops ${OpenEXR_LIBS})
```